# How to get map.getBounds() as a list of 4 floats?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I'd like to get the coordinates of map bounds as a list of 4 floats (i.e. two points in latitude/longitude coordinates).

This (Google maps undocumented feature) used to work until a few days ago:

```
var b = map.getBounds();
var bounds = [b.H.H, b.H.j, b.j.j, b.j.H];
```

It doesn't work anymore. How to get these 4 floats ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getRectFromBounds(bounds) {
    var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
    var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
    return [ne.lat(), ne.lng(), sw.lat(), sw.lng()];
};

var rect = getRectFromBounds(map.getBounds());
```

you can extend LatLngBounds and create a utility function to return this array, something like `map.getBounds().toRect()`

Comment: I get : `map.getBounds().north` : `undefined`